Switching keymap between insert and normal mode in Neovim (NvChad)
I have an alernative keyboard layout which I like to use in Insert mode in Vim, however I would like to use my ordinary Qwerty mapping when in Normal mode.
I attempted to achieve this effect by manually remapping keys for normal mode in my init.lua config file, so that they match the Qwerty layout, but I ran into a problem with the ";" key. When I press ";" or "Shift + ;", I am brought into command mode (with an initial ":"). Although I was able to remap the other keys, ";" and ":" elude the remap.
Suggestions for the cause of the issue and possible work-arounds would be appreciated :)
